# TCP/IP Matlab between 2 Computers on the same Network

Tags: matlab, networking, tcp

I'm trying to send some data in bits from one computer to another one that are on the same network using TCP in Matlab.

Currently this is what I have setup to open the connections. I'm trying to simulate a peer-to-peer connection because they need to send and receive data from each other. It works fine on my local machine when I run it using my IPv4 and IPv6.

```
 %code starts in one file
 openRecieve('0.0.0.0', 3000); %accept all connections
 openSend('10.32.41.235',3000);
```

Then I do the same in another file and I can run them i parallel on my machine:

```
%code starts in other file
openSend('10.32.41.235',3000); %IPv4 of PC
openRecieve('0.0.0.0', 3000); %accept all connections
```

The IPs are bogus...... This code works on my machine when run with 2 different instances of matlab open. However it doesn't work between 2 different computers.

Code for openReceive:

```
function connectionServer = openRecieve(client, port)
t = tcpip('0.0.0.0', port, 'NetworkRole', 'Server');
set(t, 'InputBufferSize', 3000000); 
% Open connection to the client.
fopen(t);
fprintf('%s \n','Client Connected');
connectionServer = t;
set(connectionServer,'Timeout',.1);
end
```

Code for openSend:

```
function connectionSend = openSend(host, port)
d = tcpip(host, port, 'NetworkRole', 'Client');
set(d, 'OutputBufferSize', 3000000); % Set size of receiving buffer, if needed. 

%Trying to open a connection to the server.
while(1)
    try 
        fopen(d);
        break;
    catch 
        fprintf('%s \n','Cant find Server');
    end
end
connectionSend = d;
end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can the two computers ping each other?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" look like? What error messages do you get? One thing I noticed - you have set a very short timeout `set(connectionServer,'Timeout',.1);` - is that a good idea? Not sure what the units are, but if that's ms, you are not giving yourself very long... It could take more than 100 us for two computers to find each other across a network...

Comment: @Floris The Timeout is more for the read/write and won't even be applied till after the computers have connected.....

Comment: @Slayton They can ping on IPv4s but not IPv6s as that is not enabled on my network evidently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now running although the only thing I changed was the port numbers from 3000 and 3000 to 3000 and 3001.......... Also using only IPv4 was pretty key as my network didn't allow for IPv6.

For anyone trying to write TCP code in Matlab just use '0.0.0.0' for the connection if you don't care who is connecting as it will accept all IPs trying to connect on that port #.

Current code for first file:

```
sConec = openSend('10.234.24.124', 3000); %IPv4 Address of comp your trying to connect to
rConec = openRecieve('0.0.0.0', 3001); %Accept all connections
```

Current code for second file:

```
rConec = openRecieve('0.0.0.0', 3000); %Accept all connections
sConec = openSend('10.109.22.142', 3001); %IPv4 Address of computer your trying to connect to
```